# Какой фреймворк использовать для фронтенда?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, frontend, backend

Пишу небольшое REST приложение расписания занятий, на бэкенде использую Spring Boot. Какой лучше всего использовать фреймворк для фронтенда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по вашей задаче, вам вряд ли нужен какой-то фреймворк.. но если очень хочется, рассмотрите VueJS